# How to reference a variable in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-stage

```
SET schema = 'VAI';

select  name, dob
       from vai_database.&{schema}_public.alerts as ac;
```

I have tried Executing the query in snowflake but i got the following error
 `syntax error line 3 at position 26 unexpected '&'. syntax error line 3 at position 15 unexpected '{'. (line 13)`

Comment: 1) You reference variables using $, not & 2) Where you variable is the name of the object then you need to use the IDENTIFIER keyword 3) I think (but am happy to be proved wrong) that you would need to construct a variable that contained the FQN of the table and then reference that in your SQL statement; I don't think you can build that string within the SQL statement

Comment: If you're using SnowSQL CLI, you want to set variable using `!define schema='VAI'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NickW mentioned in comment you have to use $ to reference variable.And then use identifier keyword to use it in from clause.
Also as you need build your fully qualifier table name first and then use in select.

```
SET schema = 'VAI';
SET full_name =  'vai_database.'||$schema||'.alerts';

select  name, dob
       from identifier($full_name) as ac;
```